# Hibernate: Table not found - org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am currently learning Java EE and I have a problem with JPA. It seems like Hibernate is unable to find my table called "category" (although it definitely exists!). I don't believe it is a problem with the naming, since I even tried to explicitly set the Entity table name.

I am using GlassFish (Payara) as my server.

If someone could spot the problem it will be amazing.

By the way, there should be no problem invoking private void me.yanik.booksyanik.CategoryEditor.init() (like the exception states).

In addition to the stack trace and the persistence.xml file I have provided the source code for the 3 classes I have right now and my pom.xml.

Stack Trace:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke private void me.yanik.booksyanik.CategoryEditor.init() on me.yanik.booksyanik.CategoryEditor@1a5c558f
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:122)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:162)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.bean.IsolatedForwardingBean.create(IsolatedForwardingBean.java:45)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.contexts.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:76)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:700)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:208)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:97)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:181)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1873)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:503)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:492)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:564)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1177)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1667)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:590)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1670)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1673)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1673)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:492)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:156)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:732)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:83)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:750)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:505)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4664)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2131)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2101)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy287.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at me.yanik.booksyanik.__EJB31_Generated__CategoryService__Intf____Bean__.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:410)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
    at me.yanik.booksyanik.CategoryService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at me.yanik.booksyanik.CategoryEditor.init(CategoryEditor.java:28)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
    at me.yanik.booksyanik.CategoryService.findAll(CategoryService.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:953)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1017)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4884)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4856)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4844)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1990)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1920)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2678)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2507)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1511)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529)
    ... 125 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    ... 141 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy281.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:586)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:372)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:66)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:1071)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ProfiledConnectionWrapper40.java:243)
    ... 143 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.JdbcObjectsFactory$1.invoke(JdbcObjectsFactory.java:143)
    ... 149 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "CATEGORY" not found; SQL statement:
select category0_.id as id1_0_, category0_.name as name2_0_ from Category category0_ [42102-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:5552)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1266)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1946)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2095)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1940)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1755)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1743)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:449)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:321)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:293)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:258)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:578)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:519)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:677)
    ... 154 more
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bookspu" >
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/books" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="bookuser" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Category.java

```
package me.yanik.booksyanik;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id = -1;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Category category = (Category) o;
        return id == category.id &&
                Objects.equals(name, category.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

CategoryEditor.java

```
package me.yanik.booksyanik;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CategoryEditor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.
            getLogger("CategoryEditor");
    private List<Category> categories;
    private List<Category> deletedCategories;

    @Inject CategoryService categoryService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        categories = categoryService.findAll();
        deletedCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public String addCategory() {
        categories.add(new Category());
        return "";
    }

    public String deleteCategory(Category category) {
        if (category.getId() >= 0) {
            deletedCategories.add(category);
        }
        categories.remove(category);
        return "";
    }

    public String save() {
        for (Category category: categories) {
            categoryService.save((category));
        }
        for (Category category: deletedCategories) {
            categoryService.delete(category);
        }
        deletedCategories = new ArrayList<>();

        return "";
    }
}
```

CategoryService.java

```
package me.yanik.booksyanik;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

@Stateless
public class CategoryService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "bookspu")
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public Category create(Category entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public Category read(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(Category.class, id);
    }

    public Category update(Category entity) {
        return getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void delete(Category entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method, to create or update automatically
     *
     * @param entity
     * @return managed entity
     */
    public Category save(Category entity) {
        if (entity.getId() < 0) {
            return create(entity);
        }
        return update(entity);
    }

    public List<Category> findAll() {
        CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().
                createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(Category.class));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.yanik</groupId>
    <artifactId>BooksYanik</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>BooksYanik</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Some MySQL commands:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| books              |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+

mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_books |
+-----------------+
| category        |
+-----------------+

mysql> select User from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| User             |
+------------------+
| bookuser         |
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| root             |
+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer to my question! There were a few things I was doing wrong that I wasn't aware of.

If you're using Java EE and you do not specify the `transaction-type` for the `persistence-unit` in the `persistence.xml` file, it default to `transaction-type="JTA"`. Likewise, if you're using Java SE and you do not specify the `transaction-type`, it defaults to `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"`.

Therefore, in this case I was using Java EE which means that the `transaction-type` defaulted to JTA. Without specifying a `jta-data-source`, the default data source (`jdbc/__default` on the EJB container) was being used. This default data source is a **H2** data source.

I have set up a direct MySQL JDBC driver connection in the `persistence.xml` file. Therefore, I thought that I was connecting to it. However, the default H2 data source was actually being used instead. Since my tables were in the MySQL database and not in the H2 database, my tables were not being found.

What I have learned is that if I am using Java EE, I should be using a JTA data source instead of having a direct JDBC driver connection. This provides a few advantages like connection pooling and injecting of `EntityManager`

Having said that, I have brought some changes to my `persistence.xml` file. In addition, I have created a `glassfish-resources.xml` file in `src/main/setup` as I am using Maven Standard Directory Structure. This file loads the appropriate JDBC resources whenever I deploy the web-app using NetBeans. Please note that by using MySQL8, the data source class name should be `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource`. In addition, if you're not using SSL in your development environment `?useSSL=false` parameter needs to be added to the JDBC URL.

Here are the files with the changes.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bookspu" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/books</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN"
        "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true"
                   jndi-name="jdbc/books"
                   object-type="user"
                   pool-name="mysql_Books_booksPool"/>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false"
                          connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10"
                          connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0"
                          connection-validation-method="auto-commit"
                          datasource-classname="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource"
                          fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300"
                          is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true"
                          lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false"
                          match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32"
                          max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_Books_booksPool"
                          non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                          statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8"
                          validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="books"/>
        <property name="User" value="bookuser"/>
        <property name="Password" value="password"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Books?useSSL=false"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Comment: To fully standardize your ee archive, the data source connection settings are configured at the container level, you don't need at all the file `glassfish-resources.xml` as it is redundant. The connection settings should only be specified at the container, the only data source *link* between your ee archive and the container is the `jta-data-source` and the *optional* `transaction-type`.

Comment: Does that mean that the container always needs to be configured manually using the command line in a new environment? Or there is a different way to make it automatic whenever the war file is deployed?

Answer (score 1):

I can see from the reported *stacktrace* that **H2** is been used as your data source, but from your persistence.xml you are specifying MySQL as your JPA dialect.

If the container is well configured, you will find the JNDI name of your configured MySQL data source, let's call it `dataSource`.

From there, you can modify your persistence.xml by adding the below tag inside your persistence-unit tag :

```
<jta-data-source>dataSource</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This wasn't the exact solution to my problem, but it definitely helped me to find the problem. Look at my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to mention your hibernate entities in persistent.xml under persistent-unit section as

```
<persistent-unit>
 <class>me.yanik.booksyanik.Category</class>
...
</persistent-unit>
```

Also check if you are using spring boot you need to add this to your main class

```
@EntityScan(basepackage={me.yanik.*})
```

and if you are giving explicit configuration in spring then you need to add same in configuration class

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this doesn't seem to work. In addition, I don't believe that there is a need to specify the entities since <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> is specified.

Comment: have you declared @entityscan(entity class) in spring config

Comment: I am sorry, I am really new to this. I am not using spring.